# Haskell: return all leaves of a multi way tree?

Tags: haskell, tree, traversal

Returning all leaves of a binary tree is simple enough:

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

getLeaves :: BinTree a -> [a]
getLeaves Empty = []
getLeaves (Node left current right) = [current]++getLeaves left++getLeaves right
```

But what about the case where the tree is not binary but a multi-way tree (i.e. each node in the tree can have an arbitrary number of child nodes and leaves)?

```
data MWTree a = Empty | Node [MWTree a] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I'm not looking for someone to post a solution for me; I'm just unsure what general Haskell concept(s) might be worth learning about to solve the problem of writing `getLeaves` for this type of tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested to see that `getLeaves` in both cases can be implemented in the pattern of `Foldable` or `Traversable`. `Foldable` has `toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]` which encodes the idea of collecting all of the values in a `Foldable` container `f`. `Traversable` has the more powerful `traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> t b) -> (f a -> t (f b))` which encodes the idea of a certain kind of traversal over the `Traversable` container `t`. `Traversable` implies `Foldable`

```
newtype K b a = K { unK :: b } deriving Functor

instance Monoid b => Applicative (K b) where
  pure = K mempty
  K e <*> K f = K (e <> f)

foldMapDefault :: (Traversable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> (t a -> m)
foldMapDefault f = unK . traverse (K . f)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error in your code, you are adding all the nodes of the tree to the list of leaves, which is wrong, you need to check whether some node is a leaf or not before you can add it to the list.

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Node (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

getLeaves :: BinTree a -> [a]
getLeaves Empty = []
getLeaves (Node Empty current Empty) = [current] 
getLeaves (Node left current right) = getLeaves left++getLeaves right
```

So similarly for the non binary tree (I think there is a mistake here too in your code)

```
data MWTree a = Empty | Node a [MWTree a] deriving (Eq, Show)

getLeaves :: (Eq a) => MWTree a -> [a]
getLeaves Empty      = []
getLeaves (Node current []) = [current]
getLeaves (Node current children) = if all (==Empty) children 
                                then [current]
                                else (children >>= getLeaves) 
                              --else concat $ map getLeaves children (another way of writing the same thing)
```